# Logic-level converter FET

Tags: digital-logic, power-electronics, logic-level, fet

I have been using the BSS138 level converter circuit for a while now and today it struck me I get how the voltage is stepped up by the FET or the BSS138 when you are applying say 3.3 V on the *LV* side.

What happens in the FET to reverse that and make it bidirectional?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the HV side goes low, the body diode becomes forward biased, pulling down the source to a lower voltage than the gate.

Provided the gate is pulled up to a sufficiently high voltage for that new source voltage to bias the channel into conduction, the gate pullup takes over and fully enhances the channel.

Comment: Thanks that helps, but i feel stupid now I found the answer as soon as I posted:

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/tutorialimages/BD-LogicLevelConverter/an97055.pdf

that PDF has a great explanation on page 10 and 11 of what happens

Comment: Interestingly I once plotted the BSS138 characteristics in the reverse direction and the threshold was lower than in the forward direction (~0.4V in my case) so the body diode never even conducted in this application.

Comment: I came across this brain tease today at work when I looked at one of my PCB designs and realized that my Drain and Source pins was switched and that got me thinking what actually makes it work 

says a lot about my PCB design skills LOL

Answer (score 4):

When you apply 3.3V on the LV side the MOSFET turns off (Vgs ~=0) and the 10K resistor R4 pulls the drain up to 5V.

The only pull-up on either side is the 10K resistors so it can have relatively slow rise time compared to a voltage translator chip.